# Converting string to string array: Runtime Exception

Tags: c#, arrays, string, visual-studio, type-conversion

I've got a very simple code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.IO;

namespace _3DPrinter_Test1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {    
            InitializeComponent();

            foreach (string CurrentLine_Raw in File.ReadAllLines( 
                "@D:\3Dprinter\TestObject1.gcode"))
            {
                string[] CurrentLine_Array = 
                    CurrentLine_Raw.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();

                TextBox_Test.Text = CurrentLine_Array[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The line

```
TextBox_Test.Text = CurrentLine_Array[0];
```

gives me an **IndexOutOfRangeException**.

In my opinion occured because of this line:

```
string[] CurrentLine_Array = CurrentLine_Raw.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToArray();
```

But when I replace the above with this line:

```
string[] CurrentLine_Array = { "Hello World" };
```

then I can read the **Hello World** in my TextBox.

Am I doing something wrong with the conversion from ***string*** to ***string[]***?

Comment: What exactly are you _trying to do_ with the `Select` call? You'll get an exception if some line in the file does not have any characters. Check `CurrentLine_Array.Length` to see if there is anything in the array.

Comment: OK., it was my fault...

One line in my **.gcode** file didn't conain any character at all.
I just put the whole loop into a try{} and catch{} function and it works now :)

Comment: You don't...need...to catch an exception here! Just check if the array's length is more than 0!

Comment: Of course, you are right.

Comment: An empty line is still a line. Just a single `\n` character. The returned string will be empty though. BTW what you typed converts every single character in the line into a string. Perhaps you were looking for `Split()` ? Even then, that loop *replaces* the textbox's contents. Only the last line's content will be visible to the user. Are you sure about that? Why not skip to the end directly then?

Comment: Since `CurrentLine_Raw` is a string containing a line from the file, why do you want to convert that into `CurrentLine_Array` which is an array of one-char strings from the line? If the line is `"Hello World"`, do you want `{ "H", "e", "l", "l", "o", " ", "W", "o", "r", "l", "d", }`? If one line is empty, do you want the empty array for that?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have seen the problem here:

```
File.ReadAllLines("@D:\3Dprinter\TestObject1.gcode")
```

should probably read as

```
File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\3Dprinter\TestObject1.gcode")
```

the way it currently is, it probably is not finding a file and is returning a null; Because strings are allowed to be null it enters the loop once then falls over when it tries to get a value from an array that does not exist.

Comment: Oh, just made a type-error there... This error is not in my actual program, else it would have given me a RuntimeException directly in the **foreach**-loop.
BTW, the solution is in the comments on the original question :)

Comment: Ah cheers, didn't see that. I always use try and catch as I'm programming and throw out as many of my values to the error reporting as I can, that way I know exactly what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is one or more empty lines in your file.

you can easily solve this problem by checking if the array size is bigger than 0.

like that:

```
 if (CurrentLine_Array.Length > 0)
        {
            // DO SOMETHING
        }
```

**IndexOutOfRangeException.** is mainly caused by trying to get a value of a corresponding Index inside an array that is actually smaller than the Index you're looking for.